# Rest Webservice: Incorrect values coming into argument

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey-2.0

Hi I am trying to build a REST service below is my rest method

```
@POST
@Path("/updateDocument/{id}")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response updateDocument(@FormDataParam("doc") InputStream documentStream,@FormDataParam("doc") FormDataContentDisposition header, @FormDataParam("xmlData") String xmlMetaData,@PathParam("id") String docId) {
    logger.info("Inside DocumentEndpointImpl::updateDocument");
    logger.info("XML Recived"+xmlMetaData);
    logger.info("DOCID:"+docId);
    Response response=null;
    try {
        if(documentStream==null)
        {
            logger.info("Document stream is null");
        }
        else
        {               
            byte[] documentBytes=IOUtils.toByteArray(documentStream);
            this.documentTrigger.updateDocument(documentBytes, xmlMetaData, docId);
            writeImage(documentBytes);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(documentStream!=null){
            try {
                documentStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
            }
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

I'm trying to upload a file along with one more XML data.
For this purpose i am using Form-data and hence content-type is multipart\form-data

```
Below is my POST request as extracted from POSTMAN

POST /rs/document/updateDocument/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7000
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: efaf61b8-1eb5-9657-17f5-ca877c3100a9
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="doc"; filename=""
Content-Type: 


----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xmlData"

a
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

But i'm getting content of data (this is file) into xmlMetaData and in documentStream 0 bytes comes(i found it after converting it into byte array)

After doing random tests i found that whatever value i give first in post request(in above case file) inserts into xmlMetaData and nothing comes in documentStream.

Please let me know if there is any mistake that i'm making. Let me know if more code is required
Screenshot of postman
[image]

Comment: You're expecting a `doc` field, but you are sending a `data` field.

Comment: Oops. There was problem in post script. I'll edit the question. The issue persists with doc even

Comment: Can you post an image of your exact request from Postman.

Comment: Sure i will do tomorrow

Comment: @peeskillet: i have added screenshot